# Filter data with .indexOn rules in Firebase realtime database with AngularJS

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I'm using FireBase realtime database structure like shown below. and want to extract all **model** which has `red` color.

**FireBase**

```
{
  "models": {
    "model1": {
      "modelName": "model 1",
      "color": {
        "red": true,
        "blue": true,
        "green": true
      }
    },
    "model2": {
      "modelName": "model 2",
      "color": {
        "yellow": true,
        "blue": true,
        "green": true
      }
    },
    "model3": {
      "modelName": "model 3",
      "color": {
        "red": true,
        "yellow": true,
        "pink": true
      }
    },
    "model4": {
      "modelName": "model 4",
      "color": {
        "red": true,
        "orange": true,
        "white": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i tried using below query but not getting expected result.

**AngularJS**

```
let fbRef = firebase.database().ref('models');

fbRef
    .orderByChild('red')
    .equalTo(true)
    .once('value', function(data){
      console.log('result : ', data);
    });
```

**FireBase Rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,

    "$modelID": {
      ".read": true,
      ".indexOn": ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "pink", "white", "yellow"]
    }

  }
}
```

**Expected Results**

```
{
  "model1": {
    "modelName": "model 1",
    "color": {
      "red": true,
      "blue": true,
      "green": true
    }
  },
  "model3": {
    "modelName": "model 3",
    "color": {
      "red": true,
      "yellow": true,
      "pink": true
    }
  },
  "model4": {
    "modelName": "model 4",
    "color": {
      "red": true,
      "orange": true,
      "white": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by `'color/red'`, as follows:

```
  fbRef
    .orderByChild('color/red')
    .equalTo(true)
    .once('value', function(data) {
      //Use the val() method of the DataSnapshot
      console.log('result : ', data.val());
      //Or loop over children
      data.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log('childKey : ', childKey);
        console.log('childData : ', childData);
      });
    });
```

Since you get a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot), you may either use the [`val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val) method to get the result as an object or use [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#foreach) to "enumerates the top-level children in the DataSnapshot". One of the difference between the two ways is that "the ordering of data in the JavaScript object returned by `val()` is not guaranteed to match the ordering on the server" as explained in the doc.

Comment: Thanks for solution @renaud-tarnec ..works like a charm :)